Angular file-saver package replace special characters with underscore
I am creating in back end string connected with Latin and Arabic characters. I would like to create this string in Left To Right order:
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
var fileName = new StringBuilder();
string city = "جزيرة شقر"; //or for example "New York"
fileName.Append("X_123-");
fileName.Append("Text-");
fileName.Append(city);
fileName.Append("-" + "\u202A" + "456");
Console.WriteLine(fileName);

The only way I have found to maintain the correct order is to use a special character befor the numeric value, which comes after the Arabic text “\202A”
But when I return this value to angular and using the import fileSaver from 'file-saver' call the fileSaver.saveAs method where filename is my generated string it overrides the underscore special character and instead of the value “456” I have “_456”. Where, for example, if I use C# File.Create then I get the correct value of “456”.
For me it looks like issue with file-saver, but don't I have no idea how to get around it.
